# How to make reference to an android library project inside Android.mk

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am using an android library project in my application. *android-uitableview* is the name of the android library project.

How should I add it inside Android.mk file

Following is my current Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v4
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := FollowMe
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

How will I add the above mentioned android library project, such that it is identified during compilation?

Any help is much appreciated.